# Problem with Standardization for a linear regression model with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Using the data as I find it in the original df I get some decent results with a linear regression using sklearn
But I read that when the values are very different it is better to normalize or standarize. I do so with StandardScaler but the results are out of any logic.
Please can you find where is my error ??

```
import pandas as pd
insurance = pd.read_csv("./insurance2.csv")
insurance.head()


    age sex bmi children    smoker  charges
0   19  1   27.900  0   1   16884.92400
1   18  0   33.770  1   0   1725.55230
2   28  0   33.000  3   0   4449.46200
3   33  0   22.705  0   0   21984.47061
4   32  0   28.880  0   0   3866.85520

X = insurance.drop(['charges'], axis = 1)   
y = insurance.charges    

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0)
```

Linear Regression with data as it is

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression  
MLR = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)  
MLR.fit(X_train, y_train) 
y_pred_MLR = MLR.predict(X_test)

results = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred_MLR})
results



     Actual     Predicted
1247 1633.9618  9692.885550
609  8547.6913  14503.324553
393  9290.1395  15207.774334
503  32548.3405 8435.748430
198  9644.2525  13019.558091
... ... ...
823  12523.6048 15787.241603
969  10702.6424 16050.896025
1326 9377.9047  15409.298487
792  21195.8180 13856.597356
634  14410.9321 18706.442066
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
accuracy_MLR = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_MLR)
print("Accuracy con MLR: ", accuracy_MLR)
Accuracy con MLR:  0.13064545399288352
```

```
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

RMSE_MLR = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_MLR))
print("RMSE for Testing Data: ", RMSE_MLR)
RMSE for Testing Data:  11776.684328389369
```

LR with data standarized

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X2_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X2_test = sc.transform(X_test)

MLR2 = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)  
MLR2.fit(X2_train, y_train)  

y_pred_MLR2 = MLR2.predict(X2_test)

results2 = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred_MLR2})
results2

      Actual    Predicted
1247 1633.9618  -7937.729692
609  8547.6913  -3397.232400
393  9290.1395  -2282.260721
503  32548.3405 13500.743967
198  9644.2525  -6194.481022
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

accuracy_MLR2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_MLR2)
print("Accuracy con MLR: ", accuracy_MLR2)
Accuracy con MLR:  -1.0909061875014818
```

```
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

RMSE_MLR2 = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_MLR2))
print("RMSE for Testing Data: ", RMSE_MLR2)
RMSE for Testing Data:  18263.829458461096
```

Comment: What does values like 'mse', 'mae', 'rmse' etc. gives you

Comment: updated with that info the post. thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you fit with `fit_intercept=False`?

Comment: I found in the first steps (when analysing the original data) that 2 of the variables crossed at (0,0) so I included it. Run the regression with and without the fit_intercept=False and had the same results.  But I just found after checking again that removing the fit_intercept  in the standarized attempt that I have the same results that with the non-standarized set. 
So, if fit_intercept=False is used I get really weird numbers in the standarized set.
I fit_intercept=False is removed I get the same with standarized or not standarized.

Comment: maybe this is just a consequence of trying to use linear. If the LR can not fit the data in anyway the numbers are behaving like that.